# Why are my box plot and probability plot overlapping

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to plot Histograms, Probability Plots, and Boxplots, however, boxplots and prob plots overlap:

[image]

This is the code in Python (Jupyter Notebook):

```py
def outlier_plot(df, variable):
    plt.figure(figsize = (16, 4))
    
    plt.subplot(1,3,1)
    sns.histplot(df[variable], bins = 30)
    plt.title("Histogram"),
    
    plt.subplot(1,3,3)
    stats.probplot(df[variable], dist="norm",plot=plt)
    plt.ylabel("RM Quantiles"),
    
    plt.subplot(1,3,3)
    sns.boxplot(y=df[variable])
    plt.title("Boxplot")
    
    plt.show()

for i in num_cols:
    outlier_plot(df,i)
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqQoG.png

Answer (score 2):

It may be because your code for your prob plots has the incorrect `subplot` coordinates.

So instead of:

```
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
stats.probplot(df[variable], dist="norm",plot=plt)
plt.ylabel("RM Quantiles"),
```

Try:

```
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
stats.probplot(df[variable], dist="norm",plot=plt)
plt.ylabel("RM Quantiles"),
```